# JQuery Ajax Submit Error Messages Stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which has required fields. They display errors when you click continue but do not enter anything into the required fields. If you click continue again without entering anything into the required fields, the previous error message stays, and a new one is created underneath it. What should I do so this does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you clearified the structure and how you want it to work, this should work for you.  Just remove all previous error messages everytime the form is submitted.

```
function submit_ajax_form() {
  $('.error_span').remove();
  // submits the form with Ajax especting a JSON response
  $('#usermgmtform').ajaxSubmit({
    success: function(response, statusText, xhr) {
      if (response['status'] == 'ok') {
        window.location.replace(response['location']);
      } else {
        jQuery.each(response['errors'], function(field, errors) {              
          jQuery.each(errors, function(i, error) {
            $fieldId = $('#id_'+field);                
            $fieldId.closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
            $fieldId.parent().append($('<span class="error_span">').addClass('help-inline').append(error));
          })
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: sorry, I was attempting to edit my answer in case you had your html structured like that, but I seem to have got a stray pre tag somewhere.  If you have it working though I'll give up.  You can try replacing the else part of your success function with the new edited code.

Comment: yes, thats what I did but I get the same result. If I leave `$fieldId.parent().html('');` in my code, the required input fields get removed means there is no place to input them. However, if I remove the `$fieldId.parent().html('');`, then it works except the error messages continue to be displayed even when the required field has something in it when submit button is clicked.

Comment: @mikros0ft could you post the html structure of the inputs

Comment: @mikros0ft Ok.  The new edited answer should work for you.  Its simpler as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this

```
$fieldId.parent().append($('<span>').addClass('help-inline').append(error));
```

**TO**

```
var fieldParent = $fieldId.parent();
if( fieldParent.has('#form-error') ) {
   $('#form-error').text(error);
} else {
   fieldParent.append(
      $('<span>', {
         id: 'form-error',
         'class': 'help-inline',
         text: error
      })
   );
}
```